# PEP 586: How does Literal actually help variable return types?

Tags: python, numpy, python-typing, pep

### Context

I have just read the [PEP 586](https://peps.python.org/pep-0586/). In the motivation the authors say the following:

> numpy.unique will return either a single array or a tuple containing anywhere from two to four arrays depending on three boolean flag values.
>
> (...)
>
> There is currently no way of expressing the type signatures of these functions: PEP 484 does not include any mechanism for writing signatures where the return type varies depending on the value passed in.
>
> **We propose adding Literal types to address these gaps.**

But I don't really get how adding `Literal` types helps with that. And also I wouldn't agree with the statement that

> PEP 484 does not include any mechanism for writing signatures where the return type varies depending on the value passed in.

As far as I understand, `Union` can be used in such a case.

### Question

How can the [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) return type be annotated with [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The problem that [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) solves

You took exactly the right passage from PEP 586. To highlight the two crucial words here one more time, this is about

> signatures where the return type varies **depending** on the **value** passed in.

That is one of the applications for the `Literal` type. And the statement is in fact correct.

Could you annotate a function that returns one of two different types *under various (not further defined) circumstances* before? Sure, as you correctly pointed out, a [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) can be used for that.

Could you annotate a function that returns one of two different types *depending on different argument **types*** (or combinations thereof) passed into it? Yes, that is what the [`@overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) decorator is for.

But annotate a function that returns one of two different types *depending on the **value** of an argument* passed into it? This was not possible before `Literal`.

To accomplish that, we now use `Literal` in combination with the `@overload` decorator. Consider the following example before we get to `np.unique`.

---

### Simple example

Say I have a very silly function `double` that doubles a `float` passed as an argument to it. But it can return either a `float` again or return it as a `str`, if a special flag is set as well:

```py
from typing import Union

def double(
    num: float,
    as_string: bool = False,
) -> Union[float, str]:
    num *= 2
    if as_string:
        return str(num)
    return num
```

Now, this annotation is perfectly fine. The return type captures both possible situations, the `float` and the `str` being returned.

But, say now I have another function that accepts *only* a `str`:

```py
def need_str(x: str) -> None:
    print(x.startswith("2"))
```

What do I do, if I want to pass the output of `double` as argument to `need_str`?

```py
output = double(1.1, as_string=True)
need_str(output)
```

This is a problem for a strict type checker. Though the code runs fine because as ***we* know** since we pass `as_string=True`, the `output` is a string. The static type checker (`mypy` here) only sees the return type of the first and the parameter type of the second function and rightfully complains:

```
error: Argument 1 to "need_str" has incompatible type "Union[float, str]"; expected "str"  [arg-type]
```

It sees that `output` could well be a `float`. It doesn't know what `double` does inside. How do we fix that? Well, before `Literal`, the simplest solution I can think of would have been to do something like this:

```py
output = double(1.1, as_string=True)
assert isinstance(output, str)
need_str(output)
```

That is reasonable, satisfies the type checker and gets the job done.

But now that we have `Literal`, we can solve this (arguably) much more elegantly:

```py
from typing import Literal, Union, overload

@overload
def double(
    num: float,
    as_string: Literal[False],
) -> float: ...

@overload
def double(
    num: float,
    as_string: Literal[True],
) -> str: ...

def double(
    num: float,
    as_string: bool = False,
) -> Union[float, str]:
    num *= 2
    if as_string:
        return str(num)
    return num
```

Now, if I try this again, the type checker understands the specific call to `double`, infers the returned value to be of type `str` and considers the next function call to be type safe:

```py
output = double(1.1, as_string=True)
need_str(output)
```

Adding `reveal_type(output)` makes `mypy` tell us `Revealed type is "builtins.str"`.

I hope this illustrates the capabilities this introduces and that they did not exist before. There are other things you can do with `Literal`, but that is offtopic.

---

### How this helps `np.unique`

As the documentation you linked reveals, [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) has essentially four different possible return types:

1. One array of the same `dtype` as `ar`
2. A 2-tuple of one array of the same `dtype` as `ar` followed by one integer array
3. A 3-tuple of one array of the same `dtype` as `ar` followed by two integer arrays
4. A 4-tuple of one array of the same `dtype` as `ar` followed by three integer arrays

Which type it is (as well as the meaning of the values) depends entirely on the **values** passed to the parameters `return_index`, `return_inverse`, and `return_counts`:

1. If all those arguments are `False` (default)
2. If one of those arguments is `True`
3. If two of those arguments are `True`
4. If all three of those arguments are `True`

Thus, the situation is analogous to the simple example from above. It's just that there are a *lot* more `@overloads` to define, since we have *2<sup>3</sup> = 8* combinations of arguments to reflect in our calls.

Now, if I had too much time on my hands and wanted to write a useless wrapper around `np.unique`, I would demonstrate how `Literal` can be used to properly annotate all different call variations and satisfy even the strictest type checker...

*sigh*

##### A useless wrapper around `np.unique`

```py
from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import Literal, TypeAlias, TypeVar, Union, overload

import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray

T = TypeVar("T", bound=np.generic)
NPint: TypeAlias = np.int_

# All options `False`:
@overload
def np_unique(
    items: Sequence[T],
    *,
    return_index: Literal[False],
    return_inverse: Literal[False],
    return_counts: Literal[False],
) -> NDArray[T]: ...

# One option `True`:
@overload
def np_unique(
    items: Sequence[T],
    *,
    return_index: Literal[True],
    return_inverse: Literal[False],
    return_counts: Literal[False],
) -> tuple[NDArray[T], NDArray[NPint]]: ...

@overload
def np_unique(
    items: Sequence[T],
    *,
    return_index: Literal[False],
    return_inverse: Literal[True],
    return_counts: Literal[False],
) -> tuple[NDArray[T], NDArray[NPint]]: ...

@overload
def np_unique(
    items: Sequence[T],
    *,
    return_index: Literal[False],
    return_inverse: Literal[False],
    return_counts: Literal[True],
) -> tuple[NDArray[T], NDArray[NPint]]: ...

# Two options `True`:
@overload
def np_unique(
    items: Sequence[T],
    *,
    return_index: Literal[True],
    return_inverse: Literal[True],
    return_counts: Literal[False],
) -> tuple[NDArray[T], NDArray[NPint], NDArray[NPint]]: ...

@overload
def np_unique(
    items: Sequence[T],
    *,
    return_index: Literal[True],
    return_inverse: Literal[False],
    return_counts: Literal[True],
) -> tuple[NDArray[T], NDArray[NPint], NDArray[NPint]]: ...

@overload
def np_unique(
    items: Sequence[T],
    *,
    return_index: Literal[False],
    return_inverse: Literal[True],
    return_counts: Literal[True],
) -> tuple[NDArray[T], NDArray[NPint], NDArray[NPint]]: ...

# Three options `True`:
@overload
def np_unique(
    items: Sequence[T],
    *,
    return_index: Literal[True],
    return_inverse: Literal[True],
    return_counts: Literal[True],
) -> tuple[NDArray[T], NDArray[NPint], NDArray[NPint], NDArray[NPint]]: ...

def np_unique(
    items: Sequence[T],
    *,
    return_index: Literal[True, False] = False,
    return_inverse: Literal[True, False] = False,
    return_counts: Literal[True, False] = False,
) -> Union[
    NDArray[T],
    tuple[NDArray[T], NDArray[NPint]],
    tuple[NDArray[T], NDArray[NPint], NDArray[NPint]],
    tuple[NDArray[T], NDArray[NPint], NDArray[NPint], NDArray[NPint]],
]:
    return np.unique(
        np.array(items),
        return_index=return_index,
        return_inverse=return_inverse,
        return_counts=return_counts,
    )
```

It is worth noting that with such extensive overloading, the possibilities are theoretically much greater. If it so happened that one of the options would produce an array of *yet another different* `dtype` of elements, we could still properly annotate that case here.

It is also worth mentioning that IMHO this goes too far. I don't think this is good style. A function should *not* have this many fundamentally distinct call signatures. It's what some would call "code smell"...

But as for the typing capabilities, I say better have it and don't need it than the other way around.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, that's an amazing answer! I was missing the `@overload` piece of the puzzle. Now it is crystal clear. Thank you!

Comment: Your answer should become part of the PEP and you should write a book about typing in python! Let me know when it's ready :)