# Python annotate return types for different input cases

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a function that can return different types given a boolean input argument. Currently, I just annotate it using union:

```py
def fn(x: int, ret_str: bool) -> Union[int, str]:
  if ret_str:
    return str(x)
  else:
    return x
```

However, if I annotate like this, the output of this function will be typed as a union type as well.

```py
out = fn(8, ret_str=False)  # out will have type Union[int, str] but we know it's int
```

Is there a way to annotate it such that the type checker will know if I call the function with a literal `False`, the return type has to be `int` instead of `str`?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74124522/pep-586-how-does-literal-actually-help-variable-return-types/74126288#74126288) help answer your question?

Comment: Yes, the answer you linked is helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the `typing` module and `overload`/`Literal`. It isn't the most elegant solution since it is so verbose (in comparison to most typed languages), but will cause the type checker to associate a return type depending on arguments passed. I would probably avoid doing this in most circumstances outside of libraries/modules or other code I know will be referenced repeatedly from an external source.

```py
from typing import Literal, overload


@overload
def fn(x: int, ret_str: Literal[False]) -> int:
    ...


@overload
def fn(x: int, ret_str: Literal[True]) -> str:
    ...


def fn(x: int, ret_str: bool) -> int | str:
    if ret_str:
        return str(x)
    return x
```

If wanting to implement more advanced type checking like this, it is usually beneficial to store this information in a separate `pyi` file instead of directly in your program.

Finally, please note that the `@overload` decorator is purely for the type checker. You cannot put different functionality into a function with it, since the final declaration of the function will always overwrite any previous definitions (regardless of if the decorator is used). As such, putting an ellipsis (`...`) in overloaded function definitions is the paradigm.