# What is the correct way to create a generic type hint for functions with multiple return types and conditions using the typing module in Python?

Tags: python, python-typing, typing, python-3.11, pyright

I've faced with the following problems during the type checking using **pyright** tool.

*(Python 3.11, pyright 1.1.310)*

My code:

```py
class TypeCast(str, enum.Enum):
    STRING = str
    FLOAT = float

def cast_int_to_str(value: int) -> str:
    return _cast_int_value(value, type_cast=TypeCast.STRING)


def cast_int_to_float(value: int) -> float:
    return _cast_int_value(value, type_cast=TypeCast.FLOAT)


def _cast_int_value(value: int, type_cast: TypeCast):
    match type_cast:
        case type_cast.STRING:
            return str(value)
        case type_cast.FLOAT:
            return float(value)
        case _:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Invalid type_cast value: {type_cast}"
            )
```

1. If I specify a return type for `_cast_int_value` function as:

```py
def _cast_int_value(value: int, type_cast: TypeCast) -> str | float:  # typing.Union[str, float] in older Python versions
```

then I receive the following pyright errors:

```
error: Expression of type "str | float" cannot be assigned to return type "str"
    Type "str | float" cannot be assigned to type "str"
      "float" is incompatible with "str" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)

error: Expression of type "str | float" cannot be assigned to return type "float"
    Type "str | float" cannot be assigned to type "float"
      "str" is incompatible with "float" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

2. If I create TypeVar as:

```py
from typing import TypeVar
TPossibleCastType = TypeVar("TPossibleCastType", bound=str | float)
```

and specify it as a return type for `_cast_int_value` function

```py
def _cast_int_value(value: int, type_cast: TypeCast) -> TPossibleCastType:
```

the pyright errors are:

```
error: Expression of type "str" cannot be assigned to return type "TPossibleCastType@_cast_int"
    Type "str" cannot be assigned to type "TPossibleCastType@_cast_int" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)

error: Expression of type "float" cannot be assigned to return type "TPossibleCastType@_cast_int"
    Type "float" cannot be assigned to type "TPossibleCastType@_cast_int" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

Question: What am I doing wrong? And what the feature from typing module I should use to fix this problem?

P.S. The code examples are synthetic and just for the problem illustrating

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python annotate return types for different input cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74133458/python-annotate-return-types-for-different-input-cases) You just need to overload the `_cast_int_value` signature, with one call type returning `str` and the other returning `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@overload` decorator to distinguish between the types.

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import overload, Literal


class MyEnum(Enum):
    FIRST = 1
    SECOND = 2


@overload
def enum_thing(value: int, other: Literal[MyEnum.FIRST]) -> int:
    ...


@overload
def enum_thing(value: int, other: Literal[MyEnum.SECOND]) -> float:
    ...


def enum_thing(value: int, other: MyEnum) -> int | float:
    if other == MyEnum.FIRST:
        return value * 2
    elif other == MyEnum.SECOND:
        return value / 2
    else:  # For linter
        raise ValueError("Unmatched")


a = enum_thing(1, MyEnum.FIRST)  # int
b = enum_thing(1, MyEnum.SECOND)  # float
```